# Magento 2: How can I do an integration with magento 2 and sap business one?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, webapi, integration

i want to create a integration with magento 2 and SAP B1, I created a web application in magento 2 I gave it a name and I gave it permission to API and it was saved

then create a new role, assign the roles that the API will use, then create the user who will use the roles you previously believed

when I make the call

https: // HOST_IP / rest / V1 / customer / me

give me this back

The request does not match any route.

Can you tell me if I'm forgetting a step or something?

Comment: Have you got customer token?

Comment: No, it shows an error 

2f {"message":"Request does not match any route."} 0

Comment: Which method you;re passing ? GET or POST ?

Comment: Currently GET, but the idea is to work with both

Comment: Have you checked my answer ?

Comment: Yes but it show the same error

Comment: .share your url

Comment: now thats wrong url

Comment: give me the customer uname and password

Comment: I will make you a url

Comment: are you a new in magento ?

Comment: username supposed to be email id

Comment: am im new in REST API for magento  ok here is the email testapi@hotmail.com

Comment: Okay check my updated answer

Comment: Are you using postman ?

Comment: No i'm not using postman, i'm using Telerik to test the urls

Comment: Have you checked my answer ?

Comment: yes but it show  this "The request does not match any route. "

Comment: yes, I voted for your answer, but you could change the url

Comment: Please install the postman and run the url from the answer

Comment: NOTE : use method post

Comment: just like this.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=get+customer+token+magento+2+api+%2B+postman&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9kM7L39vdAhUSTo8KHdu4DBwQ_AUIECgD&biw=1304&bih=666#imgrc=YthOYpEbaWTVxM:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magento web-API when you pass user name and password then it generates **token** for that specific **customer** (Which is only valid for 1 hour - configurable from admin)

---

> http://ventas.interlatin.com.mx/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token?username=testapi@hotmail.com&password=testapi12345

- `method POST`

---

**which returns token.**